# 'how deep is your love - I really mean/need to learn'

Tags: lyrics

I tried googling lyrics for *How Deep Is Your Love* (Bee Gees) 
but there are two kinds of different chorus lyrics.

> *chorus*
>   how deep is your love
>   1. I really mean to learn
>   2. I really need to learn

I don't know which one is correct. 
when I heard of bee gees song I could hear 'mean to learn' 
(at official video of bee gees, I can see mouth closed because of'm')
but Kelly Rowland feat. Michael Buble, I could hear 'need to learn'

and what is the meaning of 'I mean to learn'?

Comment: You can see their mouth in this video clip: [Bee Gees - How Deep Is Your Love (Live in Las Vegas, 1997 - One Night Only)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=pFg0FCx4FGs#t=110).

Comment: I've just checked that. I could see their mouth, 'M'!

Answer (score 2):

Many online lyrics are posted by fans, and sometimes misheard lyrics get transcribed.

I just checked four or five online sites, and they all listed *I really mean to learn*, so I assume that's the line in the song.

As for the meaning of the phrase:

> How deep is your love?
>   I really mean to learn...

is essentially asking the same thing as:

> I really mean to learn how deep your love is.

I would paraphrase that as:

> I plan to find out how much you really love me.

---

Song lyrics often contain phrases that don't sound very natural in conversational speech, because songwriters will sometimes twist around the order of the words to fit the meter and rhyming scheme of the song.

Comment: oh it's easier for me to understand, really, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a lot of the lyrics sites have it wrong...

I've just extracted the section from the song - it's not clear so I ran it through a couple of filters in Adobe Audition, reduced the backing and enhanced the vocal

No question, it's 'need' - the 'n' is quite clear.

***I really need to learn*** makes far more sense.

The relevant 3 seconds of audio are [here](http://pradosrural.com.au/assets/howdeep.mp3) if you'd like to listen

Comment: I' ve just heard that 3 seconds of audio, and yet I could hear 'mean ' to me. but really thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They have two versions of lyrics:

#### Original

> How deep is your love
>   **How deep is your love**
>   How deep is your love
>   **I really mean to learn**
>   **and Cause we're living in a world of fools**
>   Breaking us down
>   **When they all should let us be**
>   We belong to you and me

#### Bird and Bee

> How deep is your love
>   **Is your love**
>   How deep is your love
>   **I really need to learn**
>   **'Cause we're living in a world of fools**
>   Breaking us down
>   **They should all just let us be**
>   We belong to you and me

Answer (score 0):

It's unquestionably "mean to learn".

Watch [this video](https://youtu.be/z04ZAJTwfKw?t=32) of the Bee Gees singing it live on an interview... you'll see why I say that...

Richard